how can i use grpc-web in nuxt app to get stream of data via envoy proxy?
i want use grpc-web in my nuxt(ts) app
i used grpc in react and worked but in vue and nuxt not working
also grpc is via envoy proxy
this is my code:
GrpcClient.client.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="fetchResponse">Fetch Response</button>
    <div v-if="responseData">Response: {{ responseData }}</div>
    <div v-if="streamError">Error: {{ streamError }}</div>
    <div v-if="streamEnded">Stream ended</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const responseData = ref<any>(null);
const streamError = ref<Error | null>(null);
const streamEnded = ref(false);

let client: any = null;
let Empty: any = null;

onMounted(async () => {
  const { StreamServiceClient } = await import('~/grpc/DataServiceClientPb');
  const { Empty: EmptyMessage } = await import('google-protobuf/google/protobuf/empty_pb');
  
  client = new StreamServiceClient("http://xxxx.com:1234", null, null);
  Empty = EmptyMessage;
});

const fetchResponse = async () => {
  if (!client || !Empty) {
    console.error('gRPC client or Empty message not initialized');
    return;
  }

  const metadata = {
    "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  };

  const stream = client.fetchResponse(new Empty(), metadata);

  stream.on('data', (response: any) => {
    console.log('Received data:', response.toObject());
    responseData.value = response.toObject();
  });

  stream.on('error', (error: Error) => {
    console.error('Stream error:', error);
    streamError.value = error;
  });

  stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Stream ended');
    streamEnded.value = true;
  });
};
</script>


also i used below code to generate required proto files
protoc --proto_path=.  data.proto  --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:.  --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:.

but i get below error in console
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'CallOptions')
    at index.js?v=894431b5:67:291
GrpcClient.client.vue:30 gRPC client or Empty message not initialized
fetchResponse   @   GrpcClient.client.vue:30
Show 3 more frames

